# How to extract all the collected tweets in a single file

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hdfs, flume-ng

I'm using Flume to collect tweets and store them on HDFS.
The collecting part is working fine, and I can find all my tweets in my file system.

Now I would like to extract all these tweets in one single file.
The problem is that the different tweets are stored as follow :
[image]

As we can see, the tweets are stored inside blocks of 128 MB but only use a few Ko, which is a normal behaviour for HDFS correct me if I'm wrong.

However how could I get all the different tweets on one file ?

Here is my conf file that I run with the follwing command :

> flume-ng agent -n TwitterAgent -f ./my-flume-files/twitter-stream-tvseries.conf

twitter-stream-tvseries.conf :

> TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
>
> TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
>
> TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
>
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type =
> org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey=hidden
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret=hidden
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken=hidden
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret=hidden
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords=GoT, GameofThrones
>
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords=GoT, GameofThrones
>
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel=MemChannel
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type=hdfs
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path=hdfs://ip-addressl:8020/user/root/data/twitter/tvseries/tweets
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeformat=Text
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize=1000
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=0
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=10000
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=600
>
> TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type=memory
> TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity=10000
> TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity=1000
>
> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
> TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel

Comment: Are you using `org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource` or any other custom source? (such as [Cloudera's](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop-part-2-gathering-data-with-flume/) one).

Comment: I do use the org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource, I added my .conf in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the HDFS sink to produce a message by time, event or size. So, if you want to save multiple messages till 120MB limit is reached, set

```
hdfs.rollInterval = 0 # This is to create new file based on time
hdfs.rollSize = 125829120 # This is to create new file based on size
hdfs.rollCount = 0 # This is to create new file based on events (different tweets in your case)
```

Comment: where do I configure this ? In a file ? I'm on HortonWorks.

Comment: I'm not in HortonWorks, so I don't know where do you need to modify it. I suppose you will have an UI to manage the sink type and other params. It should be right there, can you post screenshots?

Comment: In case you aren't using an UI, the file to be edited is called flume.conf

Comment: OK thanks, I was launching Hortonworks but it's taking a while.

Comment: `TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize=125829120 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount=0 TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval=0` Try these and see if multiple events are stored into the same file till 120MB is reached.

Comment: But towards my principal problem, when I check my hdfs I have multiple files and I can't access it like it was a one big file. Let's immagine I want to put all the tweets I've collected in a spark DataFrame, with the actual state of the tweets I will have to request each FlumeData.XXXXX in hdfs instead of load a single file that will contain all the tweets. Do you know a solution ?

Comment: I don't know how to put the already stored files into a single files, but you can try what I posted in the last comment to see if the upcoming tweets are saved into a single file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands to concatenate the files into single file:

```
find . -type f -name 'FlumeData*' -exec cat {} + >> output.file
```

or if you want to store the data into Hive tables for later analysis, create an external table and consume it into Hive DB.